# writing 2D array Ncurses C

Tags: c, ncurses

I want to write a 2D character array to standard output using Ncurses.  Is there a way I can directly set a 2D array of characters to a window without having to set single values to the window with things such as waddch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not such function and (IMHO) a library should not provide those kind of things.

Consider using [waddstr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/waddstr) in a loop:

```
void func(WINDOW *window, int rows, int cols, char (*arr)[cols])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        waddstr(window, arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char arr[][6] = {"hello", "bye"};

    func(window, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr), sizeof(*arr), arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, you can simplify this using an array of pointers to `char` instead of a pure 2D array of `char`s:

```
void func(WINDOW *window, char **ptr)
{
    while (*ptr != NULL) {
        waddstr(window, *ptr++);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *arr[] = {"hello", "bye", NULL};

    func(window, arr);
    return 0;
}
```